# Custom view with children inside it(buttons, edittexts, etc.)

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have custom view which extends imageview (with glow touch). I want to add elements like buttons, textviews, to make glow touch when they are touched. I read that custom view cannot have children because only layouts can have them.

Is there any workaround to solve this stuff?

**Code**:

```
public class CustomView extends ImageView{
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    .........

    }
```

With regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the fact that only layouts (ViewGroups) can contain Views, and Views itself can not.

Instead of making a custom View, you can make a custom ViewGroup. In there you can add the Views you need, like the ImageViews and the others you mention (Buttons, EditText, etc).

Comment: can I assign to custom layout such properties as to my custom view? For example, can onTouchlistener be overrided for custom layout?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. You need to watch out though that if you add a button, you might not want the ViewGroup to use the touch. More info here: http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html